# Canvas - Get pixel color in multiple canvas superimpose

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have multiple `canvas` on my page. I want to get the pixel color of all `canvas` when two or more `canvas` are superposed.

Please see my example below.

In this example, I want to get the pixel color of all red `canvas` borders, but because the canvas are superposed, it just return the first one.

I have tried with same `z-index` without success.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas-1");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=7;
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.stroke();

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas-2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=7;
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.stroke();

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}



$('.can').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; 
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    $('#status').html(coord + "<br>" + hex + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="can"  id="myCanvas-1" width="300" height="200" ></canvas>
<canvas class="can"  id="myCanvas-2" width="300" height="200" style="position:relative;left:-250px" ></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same variable name for each canvas.

You can give them just two different global instance names.

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas-1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas-2");
```

Suposing your canvases are the same size you have to add the mousemove listener only to one.

Than get the pixel information from the two at the same pixel location inside the handler.

```
var ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');
var p1 = ctx1.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var p2 = ctx2.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; 
var hex1 = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p1[0], p1[1], p1[2])).slice(-6);
var hex2 = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p2[0], p2[1], p2[2])).slice(-6);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is same result. `hex1 = hex2` and no get pixel for second canvas. Have you a working example?

Comment: You are drawing the same thing at the same position on both canvases so the hex values are the same, that's normal. Perhaps I haven't got your question right. What exactly do you want to archive?

Comment: Yes now i have understand what you says. Thank you.